# Como comentar em python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, comentários

Estou começando a aprender a programar, e já havia aprendido o básico da linguagem **c++**, nessa linguagem existe a função de comentar a programação que pode ser acessada por `//`, mas o mesmo não funciona com o **python3**.

Gostaria de saber se tem como comentar em python3, e se sim como utilizá-la?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para escrever um comentário em Python, basta colocar um `#` antes do texto que será o comentário:

```
# Isto é um comentário
```

O interpretador do Python irá ignorar tudo depois do `#` até o final da linha.

Você pode inseri-los também em uma linha que tenha código, após o código separado por dois espaços (conforme recomendado pela [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments)):

```
print ('Olá, mundo!')  # Este texto não será considerado
```

Quando você executar o código acima, você verá apenas a saída `'Olá, mundo!'`, o restante será ignorado pelo interpretador.

Para comentar várias linhas, você pode fazer assim:

```
"""
Este é um
comentário
de várias
linhas
"""
```

Os comentários de várias linhas são muito usados para escrever "docstrings", como pode ser visto também no artigo da [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings).

Answer (score 1):

Em Python comentários são iniciados com `#`, tudo que estiver depois do `#` será ignorado pelo interpretador, portanto considerado como comentários, o fechamento do comentário acaba quando acabar a linha do interpretador.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode comentar linhas usando `#`

```
# print("Isso não vai imprimir")
```

Você pode comentar blocos usando `'''`

```
'''
print("Esse bloco não vai executar")

'''
```